# How to take care of .htaccess of all sites in multi-site setup on Linux?

Tags: multi-sites

I've read this article: http://drupal.org/node/290768 which explains multisite settings on Linux.

But I need separate .htaccess for each site. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* have separate .htaccess files in Drupal's root directory.

You *can* have different rewrite condition inside your Drupal's root .htaccess file .

You *can* have separate .htaccess inside your sites/%mysite%/ directory which will control all the files, modules, themes, etc related to that specific site.

Comment: Can you please clarify? How will sites/%mysite%/.htaccess work for whole site? I mean it should only control access for that folder only.

Comment: on a multisite setup you have sites/mysite1.com/, sites/mysite2.com, etc.  You can put an .htaccess file in these directories.  the .htaccess will control everything relate to that individual site.

Comment: No the separate .htacces isn't working. Instead I added another RewriteCond rule below the existing( in root folder) as in here: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maternityleaverules\.in$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maternityleaverules.in/$1 [L,R=301] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^articlesdirectoryindia\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.articlesdirectoryindia.com/$1 [L,R=301]